# Preferred font/size for textbox controls?

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox, font-size

Currently I'm working on an editor that uses a read only textbox to display some data for the user to check. I find that the defaults (Microsoft Sans Serif, 8 pts.) is hard to read even for me. However, when I bump it up to 9 the font looks really clunky.

What, your honest opinions, would be the best combo to produce good readability without sacrificing looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segoe UI or Calibri are common fonts for Windows, and they look good at a font size of 8-9 points.